# How to select all elements that have (any) class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I am using D3 `selectAll` to perform a transformation. I have around 260 paths but only 80 of them have a class.

How should I select all the paths that have class?

Comment: As @Gerardo pointed out, you don't need D3 for this. The simple selector string `path[class]` will do the trick or, wrapped in a D3 selection, this becomes `d3.selectAll("path[class]");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need D3 to check if an element has a class, but here is a D3-based answer. When using a D3 getter...

```
selection.attr("class")
```

... it will return `null` for elements without a class.

Therefore, all you need is checking the getter.

For instance, suppose you have this SVG with 5 paths, 3 of them having a class:

```
<svg>
  <path></path>
  <path class="foo"></path>
  <path class="bar"></path>
  <path class="baz"></path>
  <path></path>
</svg>
```

By using a getter inside a `filter` we can get only the elements with a class, even if the classes are different:

```js
const pathsWithClass = d3.selectAll("path")
  .filter(function() {
    return d3.select(this).attr("class")
  });

console.log("Elements with class: " + pathsWithClass.size())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <path></path>
  <path class="foo"></path>
  <path class="bar"></path>
  <path class="baz"></path>
  <path></path>
</svg>
```